# c# output List<List<>> to the console

Tags: c#, list, console-application

I want to test the function. and output List<List> to the console

```
namespace test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<List<int>> MoveLeftForawrd(List<int> Gameboard, int Y, int X)
            {
                  . . .

                return PossibleMoves;
            }
            
            List<List<int>> test = new List<List<int>> { };
            List<int> Gameboard = new List<int> { };
            int Currentplayer = 1;
            List<int> gameboard = new List<int> {
                -1,0,-1,0,-1,0,-1,0,
                0,-1,0,-1,0,-1,0,-1,
                -1,0,-1,0,-1,0,-1,0,
                0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,
                1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,
                0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1

                    };

            Gameboard = gameboard;

            test = MoveLeftForawrd(Gameboard, 5, 7);

            test.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);


        }
    }
}
```

but all I get is in the console..

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]
```

tell me, how do I correctly output list<list> to the console? I will be very grateful for your help.

Comment: Are you creating functions...inside `main()`? Or is it just badly formatted?

Comment: @JamesS I created a project to test it and I accidentally put it in the main. of course, I shouldn't do that :)

Comment: @JamesS while I agree that is not the best thing It is perfectly legal to have a private method inside another method as far as C# 7.0. They are called [local functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions?msclkid=ad8db0ccb1bd11ecbc44976498a7cf05)

Comment: @Vs_De_S could you please add the complete code for _MoveLeftForawrd_ because I can't reproduce your problem

Comment: you have to use `Console.Write(test[0])`

Comment: @DanielA.White it didn't help. the result is similar

Comment: `test.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);` says, for each item in the list, output it.  But each item in the list IS ALSO a list, so the output is correct.  You should foreach over the foreach

Comment: @Neil could you please show me how to "wrap" like that, otherwise I can't figure it out yet..

Answer (score 3):

You have a list of lists:

```
List<List<int>> test = new List<List<int>> { };
```

So you could iterate over each list, and then iterate over the items in that list:

```
var count = 0;

foreach(var outerItem in test)
{
    foreach(var innerItem in outerItem)
    {
        if(count>0)
        {
            Console.Write(",");
        }

        Console.Write($"{innerItem}");
        if(count++ == 8)
        {
           Console.WriteLine();
           count = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, great, thanks. Do you happen to know how to make the same output of 8 elements in each row, as I did in the initial data?

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `string.Join` and pinch of *Linq* in order to get `string` from `List<string>`:

```
List<List<int>> PossibleMoves = ...

...

string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, PossibleMoves
  .Select(line => string.Join(" ", line.Select(item => $"{item,3}")));

Console.WriteLine(report);
```

Here we join items in each line with space:

```
string.Join(" ", line.Select(item => $"{item,3}"))
```

e.g. `{1, 0, -1, 0}` will be `"  1  0 -1  0"`

and then join lines with `Environment.NewLine` to get something like

```
 1  0 -1  0
-1  0  0  0
 0 -1  1 -1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simply using layered foreach loops e.g.

```
    List<List<int>> Lists = new List<List<int>>(){new List<int>(){1,2,3,4,5},
    new List<int>(){6,7,8,9,0},
    new List<int>(){1,2,3,4,5}};
    
    foreach(var list in Lists)
    {
        foreach(var c in list)
        {
            Console.Write($" {c} ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }
```

Output:

```
 1  2  3  4  5 
 6  7  8  9  0 
 1  2  3  4  5
```